# Can I ask an answerer to Fix a broken link in their post?

Tags: support, editing, comments, suggested-edits

In this post:

[How can I put a permanent current into a superconducting loop?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69222/)

There is only one link at the bottom of the only answer. Can I ask the answerer to fix the link? How?

Comment: Note that [another editor has updated the link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/69223/44126). The updated link is to a [DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier), which should be stable for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 3):

If you know what the repaired link should be, you can [suggest an edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/editing) with the correct link.
However, that's not so helpful in this case, where the address of the broken link doesn't reveal very much about its intended destination.

After you have earned a little more reputation, [you'll earn the privilege of being able to comment on other people's posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/user/175857),
which is the usual way to make this sort of request.

For the present, I've left a comment on your behalf.